# Angular + Spring Boot + Cognito Integration

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have an angular app running on 4200 port, and the spring-boot login service app on 8080.The cognito callback is setup like localhost:4200/app/callback (on port 4200). The Cognito Auth flows works fine. It seems all my spring-boot API are protected fine, but not my angular app.

I want to have the auth flow in the backend.

Question: how can I protect the angular app having the login service running on different port? Can someone suggest a best practice on this?

Thanks